# lucee saml auth request not recognized by firefox saml tracer

Tags: request, saml, lucee

Using example below why my saml request not recognized by firefox saml tracer ?

```
<cfset uid=createUUID()>
<cfset setIssueIns=datetimeFormat(now(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:nn:ss'Z'")>

<cfset samlRequestXml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://yoursite/sso.cfm" Destination="https://youridp/sso" ForceAuthn="false" ID="#uid#" IsPassive="false" IssueInstant="#setIssueIns#" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Version="2.0"><saml2:Issuer>http://yoursite/sso</saml2:Issuer></saml2p:AuthnRequest>'>

<cfscript>

    // write the request to a file
    fileWrite(expandPath("./temp/#uid#.xml"), samlRequestXml);
    
    // Use cfzip to compress the file
    cfzip(action="zip", file=expandPath("./temp/#uid#.zip"), source=expandPath("./temp/#uid#.xml"));
    
    // read the compressed data
    zipData = fileReadBinary(expandPath("./temp/#uid#.zip"));
    
    // Encode the compressed data
    encodedRequest = binaryEncode(zipData, "Base64");
    
    // URL encode the encoded data
    samlreq = urlEncodedFormat(encodedRequest, "UTF-8");
    
</cfscript> 

<cffile action="delete" file="./temp/#uid#.zip">
<cffile action="delete" file="./temp/#uid#.xml">

<br>
<form name="form1" method="get" action="https://youridp/sso">
    <input type="hidden" name="SAMLRequest" value="<cfoutput>#samlreq#</cfoutput>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="send request">
</form>
```

this is what saml tracer show

[image: saml tracer without SAML tab]

i am expecting saml tracer would look like this

[image: saml tracer with SAML tab]

what is the correct way to do this ?

Comment: May not be related but, you should use `HH:nn:ss` instead of `HH:mm:ss` in `setIssueIns`. `mm` gets you the month number.

Comment: @rrk , yes, you are correct. I have just edited that part, but it is not directly relevant to the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the auth request isn't being deflated/encoded properly. Instead of using cfzip, I would use Java to deflate and base64 encode the string. Here's some code that I recently used to get a SAML Auth request working:

```
var samlRequest = '[your SAML request here]';
function encodeRedirectFormat(samlXML) {
    // Create a ByteArrayOutputStream
    os = createObject("java", "java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream").init();

    // Create a Deflater with default compression
    deflater = createObject("java", "java.util.zip.Deflater");
    deflater = deflater.init(deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, true);

    // Create a DeflaterOutputStream
    deflaterOutputStream = createObject("java", "java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream").init(os, deflater);

    // Write the UTF-8 encoded bytes of samlXML to the DeflaterOutputStream
    deflaterOutputStream.write(samlXML.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    // Close the DeflaterOutputStream
    deflaterOutputStream.close();

    // Close the ByteArrayOutputStream
    os.close();

    // Convert the byte array to Base64 string
    base64 = toBase64(os.toByteArray());

    // URL encode the Base64 string
    encodedBase64 = URLEncodedFormat(base64, "UTF-8");

    return encodedBase64;
}
samlRequest = encodeRedirectFormat(samlRequest);
```

I will admit that I know very little about SAML, and chatGPT did most of the work writing this function. However, it was not generated for the purpose of answering this question, and it is working code that is currently being used in production in an app I work on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Comment: I didn't use AI to generate the answer, I used AI to generate working code for myself and then used that code as part of an answer.

Comment: Right, but it's still a significant portion of your answer that's AI-generated (arguably all of it, since the code *is* the answer), which is still against the linked policy.

Comment: I would argue that my answer is "You may not be encoding properly", not the code itself. The code is simply an example showing how to encode properly, at least a method that is currently working for me.

Comment: Regardless, it's still part of your answer, and it is still AI-generated, which violates the linked policy.

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the policy, but we can leave that for mods to decide. Either way, I think this answer is helpful for AhmadZuwari, and hopefully he sees it before it's deleted (if you are correct about the policy).

Comment: There's not much to interpret here. On the linked page it says: "*An “answer generated by artificial intelligence tools” is any answer crafted in part or in whole using a tool that writes a response automatically based on a prompt it is provided.*". But yes, I agree that it's the mod's job to ultimately decide, and as such, I've raised an "In need of moderator intervention" flag to bring it to their attention.

Comment: Also just to be clear, I don't think you have any ill-intentions here like most people that use AI to post answers do. However, rules are rules, and if they were applied selectively, they wouldn't be very good rules.

Comment: Hi everyone, apologies for the delayed response. This issue has been ongoing, and since no one responded within the timeframe I needed, I changed my approach by using the 'post' method instead of the 'get' method, and it worked. Thank you for all the feedback you provided. I agree with HDuck's observation that the authentication request is not being properly deflated/encoded using cfzip. This is likely the reason why the sent request is not being rendered correctly.